# How to play avi in opensolaris?

Tags: avi, opensolaris

need help with installing free software for avi playback in opensolaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPlayer](http://solaris.homeunix.com/?q=node/24) for OpenSolaris should handle it well.

Comment: it works after some manipulation in video tab